# invalid operands of types int and double to binary 'operator%'

Tags: c++

After compiling the program I am getting below error

```
invalid operands of types int and double to binary 'operator%' at line 
"newnum1 = two % (double)10.0;"
```

Why is it so?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num;
    double two = 1;
    double newnum, newnum1;
    newnum = newnum1 = 0;
    for(num = 1; num <= 50; num++)
    {

        two = two * 2;
    }
    newnum1 = two % (double)10.0;
    newnum = newnum + newnum1;
    cout << two << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(double)10.0` this typecast does nothing. 10.0 is already double type. 10.0f is float type, and 10 is (signed) integer type.

Comment: @Lundin: `10` is specifically of type `int`, not just of any arbitrary signed integer type.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Because `%` is only defined for integer types. That's the modulus operator.

**5.6.2 of the standard:**

> The operands of * and / shall have arithmetic or enumeration type; the
>   operands of % shall have integral or enumeration type. [...]

As Oli pointed out, you can use `fmod()`. Don't forget to include `math.h`.

Comment: usage: include `math.h` and then use `fmod(15, 2);`.  More in the [`fmod` docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/).

Answer (score 20):

Because `%` only works with integer types.  Perhaps you want to use `fmod()`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. % operator is not defined for double type. Same is true for bitwise operators like "&,^,|,~,<<,>>" as well.